# My python program keeps returning the wrong value doubled

Tags: python

We are supposed to create a program that for positive   integer n,  the factorial   of  n

3. factorial_cap(1) → 1 ......#1!=1

This is my code.

```
def factorial(num):
F = 0
x = 1
factor = 1
while (F <= num):
    for i in range(1,x + 1):
        factor = (factor * i)
        if (F>=num):
            return x
        else:
            x = x+1
    print("The answer is", x)
    F = factor
```

factorial_cap(24)
    I'm just using print statement to see what the output is, it keeps giving me
The answer is 2
The answer is 4
The answer is 8,
while the right answer is supposed to be 4, I can't stop it from looping and just return the value 4

Comment: Just try doing a few loop iterations in your head and see what happens. Especially check, how often `x` and `factor` are being updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it keep printing the "the answer is" string is that the `print` statement is placed directly inside the while loop, so it will trigger for every new attempt.

Try this approach (Python 2.7.8):

```
def factorial_cap(num):
    print "Input number:", num
    F = 1
    x = 1
    while (F < num):
        x += 1
        F *= x

    print "The answer is:", x
    return x

for t in xrange(0,30):
    factorial_cap(t)
    print
```

Or this (less efficient):

```
def factorial(num):
    res = 1
    for i in xrange(1,num+1):
        res *= i
    return res

def factorial_cap(num):
    print "Input number:", num
    F = 0
    x = 0
    while (F < num):
        x = x+1
        F = factorial(x)

    print "The answer is:", x
    return x

for t in xrange(0,30):
    factorial_cap(t)
    print
```